# How do I install 9.04 in VMWare?

Tags: server, installation, windows-7, vmware, 9.04

I am about to install Ubuntu on VMWare (my host PC is Windows 7). Are there any tutorials (Step - by - Step) that I can look into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, I mean there probably are, but Ubuntu's pretty easy to setup. The oldest version I ever setup was 6.10, and it was pretty much the same as 10.10 was two months ago.

It's really easy. Just follow the prompts. (Unless you mean the VMWare part, that's also easy, just load the iso file and say boot)

Comment: Phew! That easy? I will give it a try, if I run into some problems...I will always come back here. Better still, I will post a How - To series.